# Where are the Home Directory Contents / Settings Cached in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, themes, home-directory, cache

On a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine, some settings related to the theme turned everything in the GUI (xfce) unreadable. I logged out, logged in as another user, deleted that previous user's directory and recreated it as an empty directory, like

```
rm -r /home/user
mkdir /home/user
chown user.user /home/user
```

When I logged back in as 'user', some of the theme settings were somehow still there. Where are these being stored if not in the user's home directory? How can I get rid of them to give a user a completely fresh start?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Did you actually delete everything?  as a `rm * -rf` does not delete any files starting with "." - and it's in ~/.local/, ~/.config` etc that config files usually exist. XFCE stores most in `~/.config/xfce4/` that I suspect is what you were trying to delete, but missed.

Comment: Thanks but I definitely deleted the entire directory (rm -rf /home/user), rather than contents within it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. After logging out, there were still a bunch of processes running as the user I wanted to give a fresh start to (systemd, dbus processes, gvfs processes and more). If I log out, kill all those and *then* recreate the home directory I then get the fresh start I was looking for.